# What to do when it is appropriate to give the same answer to more than one post?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Here is the problem:

I searched for a certain answer and found 3 relevant posts in different but related questions.

So I answered one of them and duplicated it to others. One of the reviewers deleted the duplicates saying that it's not allowed.

I do understand the issue and the logic. But on the other hand, people reaching those other questions will be interested in my solution.

So how do I present my solution to the other questions? Maybe comment?

Comment: If the questions are the same they should be made into duplicates, if not, how can the same answer apply equally to them all?

Comment: They do resemble each other, but not the same. In this issue it was on how to ID that a certain request is related to a Cordova App. I suggested altering the User Agent in a specific way.

Comment: Can you link to these questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, if your answer fits on all those question without alteration I highly doubt those question are not a duplicate of each other.

You claim that is not the case which should be come clear from your answer. You could always choose the safe side by opening with *I answered a similar question [here](link to post) but in your specific case you'll need to apply that answer as follows: [rest of your answer, made specific for this case]*

One other option is to edit-in the specific changes needed for the other questions in your original answer. Something like *Other possible causes can be.... you have to change the following...* to address the issues encountered in the other questions. You can then close flag/vote those other question as a duplicate of the question with your now canonical answer.

Comment: perfectly answered

Comment: I disagree with your start: *If your answer fits on all those question without alteration I highly doubt those question are not a duplicate of each other.* This could easily be so I think. I can't recall one right now but it wouldn't be extremely rare. I agree with: `I answered a similar question [here](link to post)`

Comment: I like the contradiction in your comment: *It could easily be but I can't recall one right now*...

Comment: @rene Not necessarily a contradiction. Just laziness.

Comment: @rene Maybe I shouldn't have used the word 'easily'.

Comment: @Loko your point is not invalid and my *highly doubt* leaves the possibility open that questions exist that can have the same answer without the questions being duplicates. I have the same problem as you: I don't have an example ready and I'm also to lazy to search for any. I could add *In general*  to make clear what the intent is?

Comment: @rene After I read this comment, I understand what you're saying in your answer. I understood it the wrong way before. I probably just read too quick.